# Application doesn't work on older MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, osx-elcapitan, py2app

I'm using MacOSX 10.11.4 and I tried to create my standalone MacOSX applications with using Python py2app. Everything is good when i execute my application on others MacOSX 10.11.4 but when i tried to do it on some older version like 10.11.3 or Yosemite, it appears `Illegal Instruction: 4`

In my build script, i already used option `LSminimumSystemVersion:10.6` but it doesn't change anything. However, when i tried to block on 10.11.4  with using this option, a notice appears

> this application is not compatible with your version MacOSX.

Actually, it worked without problem until i upgraded my new version Xcode. I don't know it changed something? I'll very appreciate if you guys can help me

Comment: This is just the way things go. What kind of help do you want?

Comment: Thank for your reply @erip  , i wanna know why my application cannot be executed on older version MacOSX ? ( because it worked  before)